# Как запустить Minecraft Forge 1.16 с помощью cmd?

Tags: java, cmd, bat, jar, minecraft

Пилю пиратский лаунчер на жабе. Хотел бы запускать этот батник из кода с помощью Робота.
Перерыл весь интернет, не нашел ничего по новым версиям. Все либо 1.5, либо 1.2, либо 1.12.
Версию (ForgeOptiFine 1.16.5) качал с тлаунчера.

[image]

Хотелось бы, чтобы батник был здесь.

Заранее спасибо

Comment: Ну т.е. `java -jar "ForgeOptiFine 1.16.5"` не пашет или чё?

Comment: Да, не пашет. Во-первых: не найден главный класс, во-вторых там пробел, который я уже убрал

Answer (score 1):

Ух! Это тяжело! Понадобится подключить так-же все библиотеки в ручную...
Самый легкий для тебя путь - это посмотреть на запуск игры TLauncher'ом в общей консоли(предварительно включив её). После нажатия на кнопку "Войти в игру" в консоли нужно найти строку:

```
[Launcher] Full command: <очень длинная команда для запуска>
```

Если разобраться с этой командой, то вы будете знать, как запустить майнкрафт. Остается лишь загрузить все библиотеки.

---

P.s. *Если вы попытались запустить игру скопированной из TL командой, но игра не запустилась замените javaw на java и посмотрите на ошибку. Мне понадобилось удалить аргумент Dos.name, т.к джава не очень хорошо воспринимает пробел между windows и 10*