# Запуск Майнкрафт 1 18 2 через BAT

Tags: java, bat, jar, minecraft

пишу лаунчер для сервера майнкрафт. Столкнулся с проблемой запуска майнкрафта. Обыскал весь интернет не нашел ничего. Есть только статьи с запуском 1.5.2, 1.7.10, 1.12.2, но они довольно сильно отличаются друг от друга в плане запуска!

**Вопрос**: Как запустить майнкрафт 1 18 2 через `.bat`

Comment: Очень хотелось бы с вами связаться  вне форума. Вы не против?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Давным-давно столкнулся с подобной задачей для версии 1.16.5.
Информации про более новые версии(1.12+) мало и приходится все узнавать самому.

Дабы сразу ответить на максимальное кол-во вопросов, пишу по пунктам и подробно для версии **fabric 1.18.2** (именно fabric, что бы разобрать больше проблем):

1. Убедитесь, что вы знакомы с Tlauncher'ом.
2. Определите, какая версия вам нужна и установите её. В нашем случае **fabric 1.18.2**
3. Включите общую консоль в настройках Tlauncher'а. Появится консоль, отображающая все действия лаунчера.
4. Нажмите "Войти в игру" и готовьтесь ловить нужную и очень длинную строку в консоли: [image: [Launcher] Full command: <очень длинная команда для запуска>]
5. Копируем эту команду в *startmine.bat*, заменяем **javaw.exe** на **java.exe** *windows 10* на *windows10* и пробуем запустить... ОШИБКА! [image: Error: Could not find or load main class 1.18.2\natives]
6. Ошибка случилась, ведь в аргументе `-Djava.library.path=C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\Fabric 1.18.2\natives` был пробел. Заменяем его на `-Djava.library.path="C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\Fabric 1.18.2\natives"` (добавил кавычки).
7. Снова запускаем... Снова ошибка. `Error: Could not find or load main class 1.18.2\Fabric`. В общем, все тоже самое. Ищем в файле аргументы по ключевому слову " 1.18.2" (с пробелом в начале) и в нужных местах ставим кавычки. `--version "Fabric 1.18.2"` и `"C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\mojang\text2speech\1.12.4\text2speech-1.12.4.jar;C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\Fabric 1.18.2\Fabric 1.18.2.jar"`
8. Пробуем запустить... Запустилось!
9. PROFIT

Да, я знаю, что если бы мы выбрали просто версию 1.18.2, пунктов было бы меньше.
Вот еще немного материала про запуск майнкрафта командой:

[https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1292356/Как-запустить-minecraft-forge-1-16-с-помощью-cmd/1314154#1314154](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1292356/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-minecraft-forge-1-16-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-cmd/1314154#1314154)

[https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1250360/Запуск-minecraft-1-12-2-через-bat/1314170#1314170](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1250360/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA-minecraft-1-12-2-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-bat/1314170#1314170)

Дальше вам скорее всего понадобится вытаскивать отдельные файлы в отдельную папку... Их вы можете либо определять по полученной команде. Так-же много полезной информации можно вычитать из файла *.minecraft/versions/1.18.2/1.18.2.json*

**Если остались вопросы, задавай. Я отвечу.**

Comment: Есть вопрос. Из-за чего вообще запускают батниками? Ребенок купил игру, но обычным способом она не запускается. Пишет - похоже, что типа Вы не приобрели игру на этом устройстве.

Comment: Вопрос не этой категории. Тут вопрос о разработке лаунчера а не обычном запуске игры.

Answer (score 0):

Для этого понадобится программа Process Hacker 2 и любимый TLauncher:

1. Качаем Process Hacker: https://processhacker.sourceforge.io/downloads.php
2. Открываем TLauncher и Process Hacker
3. Запускаем нужную версию
4. Ждём когда Minecraft станет отдельным процессом: будет треугольный человечек с красным глазом, в любом случае название процесса - javaw.exe
5. Когда Minecraft полностью загрузится, нужно найти процесс майна и кликнуть по нему 2 раза
6. В окне выбрать вкладку General
7. Скопировать содержание поля Command Line
8. Поздравляю вы получили cmd команду! Теперь вставьте её в любой батник либо запустите её с помощью вашего лаунчера, в ней не будет пробелов, которые ломают команду