# Как создать свой батник для запуска minecraft forge 1.18.2?

Tags: java, cmd, minecraft

Мой первый опыт в java, и я не знаю как создать батник, я что то пробовал но не получается( Помогите пожалуйста, буду очень рад познать что то новое

Пробовал обычный батник сделать по типу запуска сервера - не помогло
Сейчас пробую:

```
java C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\runtime\java-runtime-beta\windows\java-runtime-beta\bin\javaw.exe "-Dos.name=Windows 10" -Dos.version=10.0 -XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump -Xss1M -Djava.library.path=C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\minecraft\natives -Dminecraft.launcher.brand=minecraft-launcher -Dminecraft.launcher.version=2.3.173 -cp C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\cpw\mods\securejarhandler\1.0.3\securejarhandler-1.0.3.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\ow2\asm\asm\9.2\asm-9.2.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\ow2\asm\asm-commons\9.2\asm-commons-9.2.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\ow2\asm\asm-tree\9.2\asm-tree-9.2.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\ow2\asm\asm-util\9.2\asm-util-9.2.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\ow2\asm\asm-analysis\9.2\asm-analysis-9.2.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\minecraftforge\accesstransformers\8.0.4\accesstransformers-8.0.4.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\antlr\antlr4-runtime\4.9.1\antlr4-runtime-4.9.1.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\minecraftforge\eventbus\5.0.3\eventbus-5.0.3.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\minecraftforge\forgespi\4.0.15-4.x\forgespi-4.0.15-4.x.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\minecraftforge\coremods\5.0.1\coremods-5.0.1.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\cpw\mods\modlauncher\9.1.3\modlauncher-9.1.3.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\minecraftforge\unsafe\0.2.0\unsafe-0.2.0.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\electronwill\night-config\core\3.6.4\core-3.6.4.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\electronwill\night-config\toml\3.6.4\toml-3.6.4.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\apache\maven\maven-artifact\3.6.3\maven-artifact-3.6.3.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\jodah\typetools\0.8.3\typetools-0.8.3.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\minecrell\terminalconsoleappender\1.2.0\terminalconsoleappender-1.2.0.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\jline\jline-reader\3.12.1\jline-reader-3.12.1.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\jline\jline-terminal\3.12.1\jline-terminal-3.12.1.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\spongepowered\mixin\0.8.5\mixin-0.8.5.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\openjdk\nashorn\nashorn-core\15.3\nashorn-core-15.3.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\minecraftforge\JarJar\0.3.0\JarJar-0.3.0.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\cpw\mods\bootstraplauncher\1.0.0\bootstraplauncher-1.0.0.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\minecraftforge\fmlloader\1.18.2-40.2.0\fmlloader-1.18.2-40.2.0.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\mojang\logging\1.0.0\logging-1.0.0.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\mojang\blocklist\1.0.10\blocklist-1.0.10.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\tlauncher\patchy\2.2.10\patchy-2.2.10.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\github\oshi\oshi-core\5.8.5\oshi-core-5.8.5.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\java\dev\jna\jna\5.10.0\jna-5.10.0.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\java\dev\jna\jna-platform\5.10.0\jna-platform-5.10.0.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.8.0-beta4\slf4j-api-1.8.0-beta4.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-slf4j18-impl\2.17.0\log4j-slf4j18-impl-2.17.0.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\ibm\icu\icu4j\70.1\icu4j-70.1.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\mojang\javabridge\1.2.24\javabridge-1.2.24.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\sf\jopt-simple\jopt-simple\5.0.4\jopt-simple-5.0.4.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\io\netty\netty-all\4.1.68.Final\netty-all-4.1.68.Final.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\google\guava\failureaccess\1.0.1\failureaccess-1.0.1.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\google\guava\guava\31.0.1-jre\guava-31.0.1-jre.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.12.0\commons-lang3-3.12.0.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\commons-io\commons-io\2.11.0\commons-io-2.11.0.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.15\commons-codec-1.15.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\mojang\brigadier\1.0.18\brigadier-1.0.18.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\mojang\datafixerupper\4.1.27\datafixerupper-4.1.27.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\google\code\gson\gson\2.8.9\gson-2.8.9.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\tlauncher\authlib\3.3.392\authlib-3.3.392.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\apache\commons\commons-compress\1.21\commons-compress-1.21.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpclient\4.5.13\httpclient-4.5.13.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.2\commons-logging-1.2.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore\4.4.14\httpcore-4.4.14.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\it\unimi\dsi\fastutil\8.5.6\fastutil-8.5.6.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.17.0\log4j-api-2.17.0.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-core\2.17.0\log4j-core-2.17.0.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\3.2.2\lwjgl-3.2.2.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl-jemalloc\3.2.2\lwjgl-jemalloc-3.2.2.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl-openal\3.2.2\lwjgl-openal-3.2.2.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl-opengl\3.2.2\lwjgl-opengl-3.2.2.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl-glfw\3.2.2\lwjgl-glfw-3.2.2.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl-stb\3.2.2\lwjgl-stb-3.2.2.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl-tinyfd\3.2.2\lwjgl-tinyfd-3.2.2.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\mojang\text2speech\1.12.4\text2speech-1.12.4.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\minecraft\minecraft.jar -Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=system -DignoreList=bootstraplauncher,securejarhandler,asm-commons,asm-util,asm-analysis,asm-tree,asm,client-extra,fmlcore,javafmllanguage,lowcodelanguage,mclanguage,forge-,minecraft.jar -DmergeModules=jna-5.10.0.jar,jna-platform-5.10.0.jar,java-objc-bridge-1.0.0.jar -DlibraryDirectory=C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries -p C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries/cpw/mods/bootstraplauncher/1.0.0/bootstraplauncher-1.0.0.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries/cpw/mods/securejarhandler/1.0.3/securejarhandler-1.0.3.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries/org/ow2/asm/asm-commons/9.2/asm-commons-9.2.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries/org/ow2/asm/asm-util/9.2/asm-util-9.2.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries/org/ow2/asm/asm-analysis/9.2/asm-analysis-9.2.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries/org/ow2/asm/asm-tree/9.2/asm-tree-9.2.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries/org/ow2/asm/asm/9.2/asm-9.2.jar --add-modules ALL-MODULE-PATH --add-opens java.base/java.util.jar=cpw.mods.securejarhandler --add-exports java.base/sun.security.util=cpw.mods.securejarhandler --add-exports jdk.naming.dns/com.sun.jndi.dns=java.naming -Xmx2172M -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:G1NewSizePercent=20 -XX:G1ReservePercent=20 -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=50 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=32M -Dfml.ignoreInvalidMinecraftCertificates=true -Dfml.ignorePatchDiscrepancies=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dminecraft.applet.TargetDirectory=C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\minecraft -DlibraryDirectory=C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries -Dlog4j.configurationFile=C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\assets\log_configs\client-1.12.xml -DLibLoader.modsFolder=C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\minecraft\mods cpw.mods.bootstraplauncher.BootstrapLauncher --username player --version minecraft --gameDir C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\minecraft --assetsDir C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\assets --assetIndex 1.18 --uuid 6ac4ceab4a784bc09583cefeaf321adf --accessToken null --clientId null --xuid null --userType mojang --versionType release --width 925 --height 530 --launchTarget forgeclient --fml.forgeVersion 40.2.0 --fml.mcVersion 1.18.2 --fml.forgeGroup net.minecraftforge --fml.mcpVersion 20220404.173914
```

но открывается консоль вижу что java запускается но через 1 секунду сразу же закрывается, уже не знаю что делать (

Вот что в папке находится:

[image: Папка]

Comment: Что пробовали? Отредактируйте вопрос и укажите это.

Comment: @Глеб отредактировал

Comment: Пробовали запустить свою команду из батника в консоли?

Comment: Проблема уже решина)

Comment: Ну так а ответ напишешь как сделал?

Answer (score 0):

Вот батник:

```
echo off
cls
title МОЖЕТЕ ЗАКРЫТЬ ДАННОЕ ОКНО ЕСЛИ ОНО ВАМ МЕШАЕТ! РАЗРАБОТЧИК КРИВОРУКИЙ НЕ УМЕЕТ ДЕЛАТЬ ЛАУНЧЕРА ДЛЯ MINECRAFT 1.18.2!
echo                                      МОЖЕТЕ ЗАКРЫТЬ ДАННОЕ ОКНО!!!
echo ░██████╗████████╗░█████╗░██████╗░████████╗  ███╗░░░███╗██╗███╗░░██╗███████╗░█████╗░██████╗░░█████╗░███████╗████████╗
echo ██╔════╝╚══██╔══╝██╔══██╗██╔══██╗╚══██╔══╝  ████╗░████║██║████╗░██║██╔════╝██╔══██╗██╔══██╗██╔══██╗██╔════╝╚══██╔══╝
echo ╚█████╗░░░░██║░░░███████║██████╔╝░░░██║░░░  ██╔████╔██║██║██╔██╗██║█████╗░░██║░░╚═╝██████╔╝███████║█████╗░░░░░██║░░░
echo ░╚═══██╗░░░██║░░░██╔══██║██╔══██╗░░░██║░░░  ██║╚██╔╝██║██║██║╚████║██╔══╝░░██║░░██╗██╔══██╗██╔══██║██╔══╝░░░░░██║░░░
echo ██████╔╝░░░██║░░░██║░░██║██║░░██║░░░██║░░░  ██║░╚═╝░██║██║██║░╚███║███████╗╚█████╔╝██║░░██║██║░░██║██║░░░░░░░░██║░░░
echo ╚═════╝░░░░╚═╝░░░╚═╝░░╚═╝╚═╝░░╚═╝░░░╚═╝░░░  ╚═╝░░░░░╚═╝╚═╝╚═╝░░╚══╝╚══════╝░╚════╝░╚═╝░░╚═╝╚═╝░░╚═╝╚═╝░░░░░░░░╚═╝░░░
C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\jre\java-runtime-beta\windows-x64\java-runtime-beta\bin\javaw.exe -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:G1NewSizePercent=20 -XX:G1ReservePercent=20 -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=50 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=32M -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled -Xms512M -Xmx2816M -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump "-Djava.library.path=C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\versions\ForgeOptiFine 1.18.2\natives" -Dminecraft.launcher.brand=java-minecraft-launcher -Dminecraft.launcher.version=1.6.84-j -cp "C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\pw\modder\transformerDiscoverer\2.2\transformerDiscoverer-2.2.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\cpw\mods\securejarhandler\1.0.8\securejarhandler-1.0.8.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\org\ow2\asm\asm\9.5\asm-9.5.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\org\ow2\asm\asm-commons\9.5\asm-commons-9.5.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\org\ow2\asm\asm-tree\9.5\asm-tree-9.5.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\org\ow2\asm\asm-util\9.5\asm-util-9.5.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\org\ow2\asm\asm-analysis\9.5\asm-analysis-9.5.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\net\minecraftforge\accesstransformers\8.0.4\accesstransformers-8.0.4.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\org\antlr\antlr4-runtime\4.9.1\antlr4-runtime-4.9.1.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\net\minecraftforge\eventbus\5.0.3\eventbus-5.0.3.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\net\minecraftforge\forgespi\4.0.15-4.x\forgespi-4.0.15-4.x.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\net\minecraftforge\coremods\5.0.1\coremods-5.0.1.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\cpw\mods\modlauncher\9.1.3\modlauncher-9.1.3.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\net\minecraftforge\unsafe\0.2.0\unsafe-0.2.0.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\com\electronwill\night-config\core\3.6.4\core-3.6.4.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\com\electronwill\night-config\toml\3.6.4\toml-3.6.4.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\org\apache\maven\maven-artifact\3.6.3\maven-artifact-3.6.3.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\net\jodah\typetools\0.8.3\typetools-0.8.3.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\net\minecrell\terminalconsoleappender\1.2.0\terminalconsoleappender-1.2.0.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\org\jline\jline-reader\3.12.1\jline-reader-3.12.1.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\org\jline\jline-terminal\3.12.1\jline-terminal-3.12.1.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\org\spongepowered\mixin\0.8.5\mixin-0.8.5.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\org\openjdk\nashorn\nashorn-core\15.3\nashorn-core-15.3.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\net\minecraftforge\JarJarSelector\0.3.19\JarJarSelector-0.3.19.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\net\minecraftforge\JarJarMetadata\0.3.19\JarJarMetadata-0.3.19.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\cpw\mods\bootstraplauncher\1.0.0\bootstraplauncher-1.0.0.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\net\minecraftforge\JarJarFileSystems\0.3.19\JarJarFileSystems-0.3.19.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\net\minecraftforge\fmlloader\1.18.2-40.2.17\fmlloader-1.18.2-40.2.17.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\com\mojang\logging\1.0.0\logging-1.0.0.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\com\mojang\blocklist\1.0.10\blocklist-1.0.10.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\ru\tln4\empty\0.1\empty-0.1.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\com\github\oshi\oshi-core\5.8.5\oshi-core-5.8.5.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\net\java\dev\jna\jna\5.10.0\jna-5.10.0.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\net\java\dev\jna\jna-platform\5.10.0\jna-platform-5.10.0.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.8.0-beta4\slf4j-api-1.8.0-beta4.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-slf4j18-impl\2.17.0\log4j-slf4j18-impl-2.17.0.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\com\ibm\icu\icu4j\70.1\icu4j-70.1.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\com\mojang\javabridge\1.2.24\javabridge-1.2.24.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\net\sf\jopt-simple\jopt-simple\5.0.4\jopt-simple-5.0.4.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\io\netty\netty-all\4.1.68.Final\netty-all-4.1.68.Final.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\com\google\guava\failureaccess\1.0.1\failureaccess-1.0.1.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\com\google\guava\guava\31.0.1-jre\guava-31.0.1-jre.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.12.0\commons-lang3-3.12.0.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\commons-io\commons-io\2.11.0\commons-io-2.11.0.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.15\commons-codec-1.15.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\com\mojang\brigadier\1.0.18\brigadier-1.0.18.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\com\mojang\datafixerupper\4.1.27\datafixerupper-4.1.27.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\com\google\code\gson\gson\2.8.9\gson-2.8.9.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\by\ely\authlib\3.11.49.2\authlib-3.11.49.2.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\org\apache\commons\commons-compress\1.21\commons-compress-1.21.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpclient\4.5.13\httpclient-4.5.13.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.2\commons-logging-1.2.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore\4.4.14\httpcore-4.4.14.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\it\unimi\dsi\fastutil\8.5.6\fastutil-8.5.6.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.17.0\log4j-api-2.17.0.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-core\2.17.0\log4j-core-2.17.0.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\3.2.2\lwjgl-3.2.2.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl-jemalloc\3.2.2\lwjgl-jemalloc-3.2.2.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl-openal\3.2.2\lwjgl-openal-3.2.2.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl-opengl\3.2.2\lwjgl-opengl-3.2.2.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl-glfw\3.2.2\lwjgl-glfw-3.2.2.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl-stb\3.2.2\lwjgl-stb-3.2.2.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl-tinyfd\3.2.2\lwjgl-tinyfd-3.2.2.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\com\mojang\text2speech\1.12.4\text2speech-1.12.4.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\versions\ForgeOptiFine 1.18.2\ForgeOptiFine 1.18.2.jar" -Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=system "-DignoreList=bootstraplauncher,securejarhandler,asm-commons,asm-util,asm-analysis,asm-tree,asm,JarJarFileSystems,client-extra,fmlcore,javafmllanguage,lowcodelanguage,mclanguage,forge-,ForgeOptiFine 1.18.2.jar" -DmergeModules=jna-5.10.0.jar,jna-platform-5.10.0.jar,java-objc-bridge-1.0.0.jar -DlibraryDirectory=C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries -p C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries/cpw/mods/bootstraplauncher/1.0.0/bootstraplauncher-1.0.0.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries/cpw/mods/securejarhandler/1.0.8/securejarhandler-1.0.8.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries/org/ow2/asm/asm-commons/9.5/asm-commons-9.5.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries/org/ow2/asm/asm-util/9.5/asm-util-9.5.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries/org/ow2/asm/asm-analysis/9.5/asm-analysis-9.5.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries/org/ow2/asm/asm-tree/9.5/asm-tree-9.5.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries/org/ow2/asm/asm/9.5/asm-9.5.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries/net/minecraftforge/JarJarFileSystems/0.3.19/JarJarFileSystems-0.3.19.jar --add-modules ALL-MODULE-PATH --add-opens java.base/java.util.jar=cpw.mods.securejarhandler --add-opens java.base/java.lang.invoke=cpw.mods.securejarhandler --add-exports java.base/sun.security.util=cpw.mods.securejarhandler --add-exports jdk.naming.dns/com.sun.jndi.dns=java.naming -Dtransformers.list=optifine:OptiFine:1.18.2_HD_U_H9 -Xss2M cpw.mods.bootstraplauncher.BootstrapLauncher --username MissingName --version "ForgeOptiFine 1.18.2" --gameDir C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game --assetsDir C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\assets --assetIndex 1.18 --uuid e8717b21d14941f4b2ce6455e5a14a5b --accessToken eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJFUzI1NiJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE3MDc0ODUzOTksImNsaWVudF9pZCI6InRsYXVuY2hlciIsInNjb3BlIjoib2J0YWluX293bl9hY2NvdW50X2luZm8gbWluZWNyYWZ0X3NlcnZlcl9zZXNzaW9uIiwic3ViIjoiZWx5fDQ5NDU3OTcifQ.SybKJkqa7Bv2VV9Wv7tUdeJgGE3GTcBD1tle9wo766xxVzAUh7c9Cs2un6k7i1baGUXL1m1XAfgnmrZCkcPIsA --clientId "" --xuid "" --userType mojang --versionType modified --width 925 --height 530 --launchTarget forgeclient --fml.forgeVersion 40.2.17 --fml.mcVersion 1.18.2 --fml.forgeGroup net.minecraftforge --fml.mcpVersion 20220404.173914 --server 65.21.9.198 --port 25988
```

Делал из это-го гайда:
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1426852/583813

Надеюсь кому-то помог.

Сразу говорю - где оч большая строка - это батник, которые запускает из ОРИГ тлаунчера или легаси.